# jQuery Variable attr not working

Tags: jquery, html

Look at these html and jQuery codes:

```
<button>div</button>
<button>span</button>
<div class="fill">fill</div>
<span class="fill">fill</span>
<div class="fill">fill</div>
<span class="fill">fill</span>
<div class="fill">fill</div>
<span class="fill">fill</span>

(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var buttonVal = $(this).text();

        $.expr[':'].fillClass = function(element) 
            { return $(element).attr('class') === buttonVal);};

        $('div:fillClass').css('opacity', '.2');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

when I click the button, it saves the value of button in `buttonVal`, but when I put the `buttonVal` in the `return $(element).attr('class') === buttonVal` does not work. I have changed the order of functions, but I do not know why it does not work.

Comment: Quick thing: this will no doubt work for items with a single class. If you start having multiple classes on one item, it'll break down. A "fix" would be `return $(element).hasClass(buttonVal);`

Comment: tested, It does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm going to assume that you are trying to return a boolean value of whether the class of the element is equal to `buttonVal`. In that case, you need to surround the entire statement in parenthesis like this:

```
return ($(element).attr('class') === buttonVal);
```

However, there's another issue. In your code, you have `var buttonVal = $(this).text();`. Therefore, `buttonVal` will have the value `div` or `span` depending on which button you clicked. None of the elements that you've given have the class `div` or `span` so therefore it won't be true for anything.